# Apache нужна помощь!

Tags: apache, сервер, httpd

Начал останавливаться апач и потом вообще на сервер по ssh не могу зайти с первого раза - висит жутко. Помогает только reboot.
Зашел в whm посмотреть apache status и вот что я там увидел:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Рабочих процессов реально пару штук, но вот таких "Waiting for Connection" висит штук 60-70 и они не уходят. Запросы идут аяксом, и на странице я вижу что ответ ввернулся и все хорошо, но почему они не уходят из задач Апача?
Помогите пожалуйста в какую сторону смотреть?

Comment: Если вопрос в количестве процессов Апача, то это нормальное поведение. Если вам не нравится количество процессов Апача и есть желание его уменьшить смотрите в сторону директив  StartServers, MinSpareServers, MaxSpareServers. Но чтобы их править - нужно реально понимать зачем и как. И не факт, что сервер "висит" из-за этого. На вашем скриншоте не видно, чтобы Апач грузил систему.

Comment: А то есть то что процессы долго висят в ожидании соединения это нормально? Просто у некоторых таких процессов показатель SS доходит до 1960-2000 - хотя опять же если смотреть в консоле Chrome то ajax запрос уже давно вернулся со статусом 200.
Вот это меня и смущает..

Comment: У Апача работающего через prefork всегда есть определенное количество процессов ожидающих соединения. Регулировкой "порождения" и "уничтожения" этих процессов занимается внутренний механизм Апача, и основывается на значениях директив конфига Апача. Поэтому пока ничего криминального не вижу.